# Change Date format from one format to another in Java Script

Tags: javascript

Date can be in any format **25.10.2018** or **25.10.18** or **25-12-2018** or **25-12-18**, need to change this date to **25/10/2018** this format only.

The user can input date in any above format, I need to distinguish first in which format then needs to change its format to the desired format.

***I do not want to use any 3rd Party JavaScript file.***

Comment: Yes, but have you tried anything at all? Do you have any code to share?

Comment: Use a library like [momentjs](https://momentjs.com)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/).

Check below working examples:

```js
let d1 = "25.10.2018";
console.log(moment(d1, "DD.MM.YYYY").format("DD/MM/YYYY"));

let d2 = "25.10.18";
console.log(moment(d2, "DD.MM.YY").format("DD/MM/YYYY"));

let d3 = "25-12-2018";
console.log(moment(d3, "DD-MM-YYYY").format("DD/MM/YYYY"));


let d4 = "25-12-18";
console.log(moment(d4, "DD-MM-YY").format("DD/MM/YYYY"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: "I need to distinguish first in which format then needs to change its format to the desired format."
How will I distinguish in which format entered date stand?

Comment: @Partha You can pass an array of format strings: `["25.10.2018", "25.10.18", "25-12-2018", "25-12-18"].forEach(d => { console.log(moment(d, ["DD.MM.YYYY", "DD.MM.YY", "DD-MM-YYYY", "DD-MM-YY"]).format("DD/MM/YYYY")); });` ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s5Lg1ncb/))

Comment: @Andreas you are using moment.js Actually i do not want to use any third party software.

Comment: @Partha Because this answer also uses momentjs O.o

Answer (score 1):

So your original date have included special character like `.,-` .So you can split with that characters and I add 0 for your `month and date` 1 digit.For year format , use `new Date` to get correct year even two digit have provided ....

```js
var d = '12-4-88'; // '25.10.2018'; or 25.10.18 or 25-12-2018

d = d.split(/[.\-_]/);
d.forEach((v,k) => {
  if(v < 10) d[k] = 0 + v;
  if(k == 2 && v.length == 2) {
     var year = new Date(v+"-01-01");
     d[k] = year.getFullYear();
   }
})

console.log(d[0] + '/' + d[1] + '/' + d[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need `Date` to preserve full year as two digits year value evaluates invalid date.

```js
function parse(str) {
  var result = {
    'input': str,
    'output': null
  };
  var tmp = str.split(/[\.|\-]/);
  if (tmp && 3 === tmp.length) {
    if (2 === tmp[2].length) {
      tmp[2] = new Date().getFullYear().toString().substr(0, 2) + tmp[2];
    }
    if (1 === tmp[1].length) {
      tmp[1] = '0' + tmp[1];
    }
    result.output = tmp.join('/');
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(parse("25.10.2018"));
console.log(parse("25.10.18"));

console.log(parse("25-10-2018"));
console.log(parse("25-10-18"));

console.log(parse("25.1.2018"));
console.log(parse("05.10.2018"));
```

Comment: Not correct answer. It is failing if date is `25.1.2018` or `05.10.2018` and LOT MORE. Didn't test all cases.

Answer (score -1):

```
function replaceAll(string, search, replacement) {
    return string.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
};
const newDate = replaceAll(oldDate, '.', '/');
```

Answer (score -2):

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(str1, str2, ignore) 
{
    return this.replace(new RegExp(str1.replace(/([\/\,\!\\\^\$\{\}\[\]\(\)\.\*\+\?\|\<\>\-\&])/g,"\\$&"),(ignore?"gi":"g")),(typeof(str2)=="string")?str2.replace(/\$/g,"$$$$"):str2);
} 

"25.10.2018".replaceAll(".", "/");
```